# Virtualbox: Failed to open a session for the virtual machine in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Virtualbox failed to open a session for the virtual machine in **Ubuntu**

```
**Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_SUPLIB_WORLD_WRITABLE).

Details

Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
Console
Interface: 
IConsole {8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6}
```

Any idea why do I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory: the virtualbox library or libraries are world-writable.

```
chmod o-x /path/to/virtualbox/library
```